# In D3 zoomable sunburst, how to show only one level of children

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

how can I show only one level of children in a zoomable sunburst.
I visualize a taxonomy with a zoomable sunburst. By showing only one level it will look less complex. That is what I am looking for.
Zooming, clicking on a child, should reveal the next level of children.
I can do this by splitting the data and load each node separately into d3 but is there a way in d3 to realize that with the complete set of data?

Answer (score 0):

```
var g = svg
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(partition.nodes(root)
        .filter(function(d) {                
             return d.depth == 0;
        })
    )
    .enter()
    .append("g");
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your answer. Posting only code is usually not enough.

Comment: d3 will generate depth for each and every level of your tree data structure, here i have written a filter to control at first level, means you will only see one level in the sunburst chart.
Hope this helpful